# Zend 3 - dropdown menu isn't displayed

Tags: php, forms, select, zend-framework3

After have followed the "Getting started: A skeleton application" of ZendFramework (and it works very well!), I'm trying to customize the Add a Album form.
For information, I use the "3.0.2dev" version of Zend.

In this form, I use  a dropdown menu called "language" (in Zend the component is Zend\Form\Element\Select).

The problem is there's a text input instead of the dropdown menu!!!!

Etudiant/src/Form/EtudiantForm.php:

```
        $this->add([
        'name' => 'annee_admission',
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        'options' => [
            'label' => 'language',
            'empty_option' => 'select a language',
            'value_options' => [
                         '0' => 'French',
                         '4' => 'English',
                         '2' => 'Japanese',
                         '3' => 'Chinese',
                 ],
        ],
    ]);
```

[here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIxn2.png)

I've just spent several hours to check on other websites if there's a error, but no.This type of form seems to not be recognized!!

Does anyone have experienced this issue or has a solution for that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you outputting the form in the template?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tim, I finally found the answer:
In the .phtml, I used "$this->formInput" instead of "$this->formSelect".

Since this problem is solved, do you know how to populate a select form from the database (but from another module)?
The getServiceLocator() is now deprecated in Zend 3, so I don't know how to do that.